# Given 1 Latitude/Longitude Coordinate and a distance of 5 miles - What's the distance in Pixels in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I can do this to convert a lat/lng to pixel coordinates in Google maps:

```
var xy = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

Now I'm wondering, how do I get a distance in pixels from that point?  Say I want to draw a circle with a radius of 5 miles around that.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v3 there is the [circle object](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Circle)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to draw a circle around a given point is to draw a [GPolygon](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GPolygon) with many points, simulating a circle.

You can find a good example of this [here](http://esa.ilmari.googlepages.com/circle.htm). Look for the *drawCircle* function in the source (you will need to download the attached circle.html to check it out.